# DialogFragment doesn't show up

Tags: android, dialog

At the last, I found what the problem is...

If you have a function like this:

```
public void test()
{
    DialogFragment dlg = new LoginDialog();
    dlg.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "login");
}
```

The dialog will only appear when test() finished, I'm not sure if this is the only way Android dialog works but I'll definitely read more on this...

---

**Original Question:**

I'm new to android world, can somebody shed some light?

dlg.show() executed without exception but just nothing happens, what should I do to know what's wrong? The project is using Android 2.2's API.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    ...
    DialogFragment dlg = new LoginDialog();
    dlg.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "login");
}
```

The dialog layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:hint="username" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:hint="password"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The dialog class:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

public class LoginDialog extends DialogFragment
{
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_dialog, null))
        // Add action buttons
               .setPositiveButton("Sign In", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // sign in the user ...
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // do something
                   }
               });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the first bit of your code is being called, try putting `finish()` right before you create your dialog. If your app shuts down, then there is something wrong with your dialog, but if it doesn't close then it means that your code isn't reaching the place where it creates a dialog

Comment: Yes it was called, because I set a breakpoint there and it was triggered.

Comment: @agou have you tried to remove the custom view and just set a text content? Does it work if you do so? I'm not so sure the parent `null` is correct, maybe you have to find the view with id `R.id.layout_root` and give it as parent to your `inflate(..)`

Comment: In my case `dismiss()` was called in `onCreate()` of a dialog.

Comment: The method Show() of DialogFragment doesn't allow anymore a SupportFragmentManager since V4, so I thinks this question and all answers are more then deprecated, don't waste your time here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I've added information about what caused the issue at the top of the question.

Edit (for @MarcinS' comment):

```
public void test()
{
    DialogFragment dlg = new LoginDialog();
    dlg.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "login");
    doThis();
    doThat();
}
```

The dialog does not appear immediately after dlg.show(), it appears after doThat() has finished.

Comment: What do you mean by saying 'when test finished'?

Comment: @MarcinS., I edited the reply, do you think that's correct or?

Comment: @agou To me it doesn't make sense that the dialog would only show after test() has completed, especially since it is executed before doThis() and doThat(). However: If doThis()/doThat() are longer running operations they shouldn't be executed on the UI thread anyway...

Comment: doesn't make sense. Clearly you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: See @srka's answer for the explanation. Basically the transaction is not committed till the function exists.

Answer (score 3):

Try to create your fragment using newInstance()

```
public class LoginDialog extends DialogFragment
{
    static LoginDialog newInstance(String title) {
        LoginDialog f = new LoginDialog();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", title);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

And then in your MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity // notice that in my case I extend Activity instead of FragmentActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInsatnceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInsatnceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LoginDialog dialogFragment = LoginDialog.newInstance("My Dialog");
        dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "login");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you forgot to set style of yout **DialogFragment**

Try one of this styles:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mNum = getArguments().getInt("num");

        // Pick a style based on the num.
        int style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, theme = 0;
        switch ((mNum-1)%6) {
            case 1: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE; break;
            case 2: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME; break;
            case 3: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_INPUT; break;
            case 4: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL; break;
            case 5: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL; break;
            case 6: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE; break;
            case 7: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME; break;
            case 8: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL; break;
        }
        switch ((mNum-1)%6) {
            case 4: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo; break;
            case 5: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog; break;
            case 6: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light; break;
            case 7: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Panel; break;
            case 8: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light; break;
        }
        setStyle(style, theme);
    }
```

Read more on: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

You can also set custom style for your **DialogFragment**

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.MY_DIALOG);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you used the fragmentransaction instead:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    ...
    DialogFragment dlg = new LoginDialog();
    dlg.show(getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(), "login");
}
```

**Edit:**

I'd encourage you to go take a look at googles guide on [DialogFragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html). What you are doing with custom view for the alertbuilder might be causing it to not show.

Comment: Tried this, no luck... actually before using DialogFragment, I tried this: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application , but it's the same, function show() was executed but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of a dialog not showing up after onResume. (I had a dialog informing the user that he has paused the game and ask if he wanted to continue). I simply called it to early and I think the reason was a fragment that I loaded after the dialog.show(), in onPostResume(). I solved it by detecting if a dialog.show was in the queue and simply waited to show it until onPostResume, after my fragment was loaded.

This is the function for showing the dialog:

`@Override
    public void onShowUserDialog(String title, String message, int type) {
        FragmentTransaction fm = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().
            findFragmentByTag(PublicVar.DIALOG_USER);
        if (prev != null) {
            fm.remove(prev);
            fm.commit();
        }
        if (hasPostResumed) {
            DialogFragment userDialog = UserDialog.
                newInstance(title, message, type);
            userDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(), PublicVar.DIALOG_USER);
            dialogTitle = "";
            dialogMessage = "";
            dialogType = 0;
        }
        else { //saved for later
            dialogTitle = title;
            dialogMessage = message;
            dialogType = type;
        }
    }`

hasPostResumed, dialogTitle, dialogMessage and dialogType are declared in the activity.

This is the final call when activity is resumed:

```
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    hasPostResumed = true;

    ...function for loading my fragments...

    if (dialogType != 0) {
        onShowUserDialog(dialogTitle, dialogMessage, dialogType);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`FragmentTransaction.commit()`(it's called when you show `DialogFragment`) does not commit immediately, but when main thread is ready. Since you want it done immediately, you must add `getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()` after showing dialog.

Source: [FragmentTransaction.commit()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit()), [FragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#executePendingTransactions%28%29).