# How to pop up an Android dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I have the following code which doesn't work, what should I do to debug it?

I created a new android 2.2 project, added a button and the button has:

```
    android:onClick="Test"
```

the `Test()` function is here:

```
public void Test(View view) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getApplicationContext());
    builder.setTitle("Title");
    builder.setMessage("Message");
    builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                arg0.dismiss();
            }});
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.create().show();
}
```

When it's triggered, the `show()` will cause this exception:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception WindowManager$BadTokenException))   
    <VM does not provide monitor information>   
    AlertDialog(Dialog).show() line: 245    
    MainActivity.Test(View) line: 39    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
    View$1.onClick(View) line: 2067 
    Button(View).performClick() line: 2408  
    View$PerformClick.run() line: 8817  
    ViewRoot(Handler).handleCallback(Message) line: 587 
    ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
    Looper.loop() line: 143 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4914    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

BTW There are some other things I tried: [DialogFragment doesn't show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331388/dialogfragment-doesnt-show-up/13332727#13332727)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a unique LogCat, you rewrote that by hand didn't you... :) Next time you can highlight the LogCat and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Anyway, I see the BadTokenException. Change:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getApplicationContext());
```

To:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 3):

remove android:onClick="Test" from your layout.xml and use

```
Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.your_btn);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
test();
});
```

instead

btw. you should't use getApplicationContext() ---> use this

Comment: Why must agou remove the onClick attribute? It obviously works and involves less code.

Comment: The onClick atribute was added in android sdk version 7. So it won't work on < 7 sdk versions. I think that was @angou's problem 

2. In my opinion it's better to keep logic for events outside the xml. It's more reasonable.

Comment: API 4+ supports [`onClick`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#onClick), so it won't work on [0.1% of active devices](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html). But more to the point if you don't think `Test()` was being called, how did the window throw an exception? The LogCat is clear, `onClick` is not the problem. All that aside, you should know that your code is currently wrong... Please update it.